# Table structure of active members for 4 years in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on an achievement system and the users can unlock a badge when they have been active on the site for 4 years.

I tried to store each time a user in logged in but it's not really a good idea.

So my question is, how the table structure should be if  I want to know if the user was active for 4 years?

Comment: Define active. Does the member need to log in once every day? Every hour? Do some activity every time they log in? Can they log in once a month and log out? Do they need to log in and perform some minimum task? Your table will be dependent on what you call as active.

Comment: That is not a definition. Answer the questions from my previous comment.

Comment: member need to log in once every day

Comment: what if member missed one day in 4 years?

Comment: After thinking I think a member should be logged in at least once per year for 4 years.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by active, but if you mean that four years has elapsed since they first logged on, registered etc. then you just need a date field to store the account setup / logon etc. Then when they logon you can test to see if four years has past since that date and insert a badge accordingly.

Comment: to know if a member is active we need to know if he is often logged in on the site

Comment: You could store the number of logins, the original date, and thus compute the average days between logins, but personally I'd just store all the logins - how many could there be?

Comment: If I store the number of logins my table will be very big

Answer (score 0):

That is too generic a question to provide an full solution. By active for 4 years it sounds like you will need to track their actions. So perhaps some sort of transaction or history table that links their userid with a datetime plus actions performed.

Then you just have to define what "active" means such as having performed specific actions at least once per week, etc.

---

EDIT
First off I am a SQL Server developer, but have attempted to convert this to MySQL syntax for you.

~ = primay keys to ensure uniqueness & good performance

User table

```
~    UserID     unique user id - could be an Identity, GUID or similar field
    UserName    unique user name
    anything else you want to track such as First Name, Last Name, etc
```

UserAction table

```
~   UserID              link to User table
~   ActionType          number indicating what the user performed
                            1 = login
                            add in other types in the future if you ever want to track anything else
~   ActionDate          datetime of the action
    anything else that you may want to track such as the duration or end date (in this case that would be them logging out)
```

Database systems are designed to hold lots of data so you shouldn't have to worry too much about that unless space is a factor. You can always delete any data that is older than 4 or 5 years if you like.

Normally I would just use a CTE (common table expression) but apparently they won't be available until MySQL 8.0 [https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/presentations/mysql-80-common-table-expressions/]

So instead here is another method. It assumes that you want a login within each given year. i.e. at least one login from 2017, one from 2016, 2015 & 2014. If instead you wanted at least one login going back 1 year from today and so on then we will need to modify this query.

```
-- this will return the number of years with at least one login, going as far back as 4 years
SELECT COUNT(1) AS NumberOfYearsWithLogin
    FROM (
        SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(ActionDate) AS NumberOfYearsAgo
            FROM UserAction
            WHERE UserID = 123 -- put user of interest here
              AND ActionType = 1 -- login
              AND YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(ActionDate) < 4 -- check the last 4 years
            GROUP BY YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(ActionDate) -- group by year number with today's year as number 0
    ) A
;
```

Comment: to know if a member is active we need to know if he is often logged in on the sit

Answer (score 0):

You can save the last consecutive log in and the first log in. That's just two columns. Every time a user logs in, you can check if he logged in the day before. If yes, then update that column. If not then update the first log in because that's when the 4 year period will begin again. Let me know if that makes sense or if you need examples to help with understanding the thought process.

Comment: I understand your logic but after thinking I think a member should be logged in at least once per year for 4 years.

Comment: In that case, you should check if the last login was within one year of the current date. If it is, you can update that column and if the first login is more than 4 years ago then you can award the badge. If the last login is more than one year, then you set both columns to current date.